# After receiving signal from Bluetooth device to open new activity(screen) in android based mobile app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, bluetooth, android-studio

Is it possible using Android Studio or Eclipse Indigo + ADT to develop a mobile application where the app will receive a Bluetooth signal and based on the signal will open Activity(screen)? For example I am on the first floor in a building and I am receiving this Bluetooth signal then automatically my android application will open new screen with relevant information.

If that is possible do you have an idea where can I find tutorials?

Regards

Comment: May be you run Bluetooth Device discovery in the background with some interval, once your service discovers a device in first floor, you can then launch an activity. Here is the link for Service Discovery http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#FindingDevices

Comment: @Vny Kumar thanks for your reply! However i am still wondering how to open new Activity once device is detected rather then pairing or exchanging information with it?